# Watermark text for Password Field

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, watermark

I have one password field on page. I want to display watermark  text "Enter password" in password field on screen before entering password it shows the text as password type. How we can resolve this issue by using javascript?

Comment: Of course, just marking random answers as correct isn't quite the right way to go, but good effort I guess...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is going to be to use a jQuery plugin that allows watermarking of password fields.  I came up with [this plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jWatermark) doing a quick google search.

If you don't want to use a jQuery plugin, what you're going to need is 2 html inputs, one visible and one hidden.  The hidden one contains the actual value you're wanting to pass back to the server while the visible one is the one you manipulate with javascript and the user interacts with. The next part is to manipulate the 2 inputs together. Here's the important parts that I can think of to code for:

- When your visible password input is empty, change it's type to text
  and display the watermark but leave the hidden input empty.
- If a user gives it focus, hide the watermark and switch back to
  password.
- As they type, copy the value into the hidden field.
- If they leave the input and there's no text, switch the type back to
  text and show the watermark again.

Try either the plugin or coding the javascript yourself and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

So the below code is a simple jQuery mask for a regular input field. But this won't work for a password field because the letters are masked! So that makes me think of two ways this could be extended. One would be to write a masking function yourself. So use a regular input field, but mask characters as they are entered. The other would be to overlay a regular textbox on the password field and then either hide it or change the z-order when clicked in. I know that you just said in comments you aren't using jQuery, but I am leaving this up for others. Sorry I don't have code for your use case!

```
/* Newsletter Sign Up Functions*/
    /* Toggle field descriptions as they are clicked in and out of */
    //set default input values because Firefox is stupid and doesn't reset them
    $("#newsletterform input[name=first]").val('First Name');
    $("#newsletterform input[name=last]").val('Last Name');
    $("#newsletterform input[name=email]").val('E-mail Address');

    //store default input values
    $("#newsletterForm input:text").each(function() {
        $.data(this, "initialval", $(this).val());
    });
    //clear values on focus
    $("#newsletterForm input:text").focus(function() {
        if ($.data(this, "initialval") == $(this).val()) { $(this).val(""); }
    });
    //restore value on lost focus
    $("#newsletterForm input:text").blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "") { $(this).val($.data(this, "initialval")); }
    });
    /* End toggle field descriptions */
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i need javascript methods.

Comment: Ahh poo. Just realized that password field will be masked. This will work for a regular field. It is a start though. Let me think about the masked field aspect now.

Comment: All right, updated my answer with a couple ideas to make my current code work with password fields. I am leaving my answer up though in case it helps other people that do use jQuery. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to support newer browsers you can use the `placeholder` attribute on the input.

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Insert Password" />
```

Or if you need to set it in script just do

```
input.placeholder =​​​​​​​ "Insert Password";
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/xECqY/.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely try a jQuery watermark function, ex. http://code.google.com/p/jwatermark/

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery plugin is actively maintained and handles new HTML5 input fields: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/