# Watermark on Password text input using GWT

Tags: gwt, uibinder

This has been addressed for C# in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666195/watermark-text-for-password-field) by using jQuery or by changing dynamically the "input" type. The jQuery option is probably overkilling in GWT and the change of input type I think is not possible. What is the best way to do it using GWT?

is it really necessary to do two inputs (one for the watermark as TextInput and another one for the password as Password and switch between them?)

Comment: I would suggest that instead of having 2 inputs, you have a background image in CSS with the water mark text and remove the background image when the input is focused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is to set the element's placeholder: `passwd.getElement().setProperty("watermark")`. Otherwise, use a label/span that you position on top of the input and show/hide as the field gets focused/blurred.

Comment: for compatibility reasons I cannot use the html5 properties, so I will use the span layer on top option. thanks. (although this generated another problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238265/overlapping-divs-on-the-right-edge-of-the-page/ )